# How to extract a string within a parentheses that contains the string, a comma, and an integer?

Tags: python, string, dataframe, fuzzywuzzy

I am trying to pull a string name that is within a parentheses that contains the strings follow by comma and an integer.

My current dataframe output is this:

```
print df1:

      name                                    matches      best match        best 2        best 3
0  aparna    [(aparn, 91), (Pankaj, 67), (arup, 45)]     (aparn, 91)  (Pankaj, 67)    (arup, 45)
1  pankaj    [(Pankaj, 100), (aparn, 55), (abc, 30)]   (Pankaj, 100)   (aparn, 55)     (abc, 30)
2  sudhir  [(sudhir c, 95), (arup, 22), (aparn, 18)]  (sudhir c, 95)    (arup, 22)   (aparn, 18)
3   Geeku     [(Geek, 89), (arup, 22), (Pankaj, 18)]      (Geek, 89)    (arup, 22)  (Pankaj, 18)
```

But I want the data frame output to look like this:

```
print df1:

      name                                    matches   best match   best 2   best 3
0  aparna    [(aparn, 91), (Pankaj, 67), (arup, 45)]     aparn      Pankaj   arup
1  pankaj    [(Pankaj, 100), (aparn, 55), (abc, 30)]     Pankaj     aparn    abc
2  sudhir  [(sudhir c, 95), (arup, 22), (aparn, 18)]     sudhir c   arup     aparn
3   Geeku     [(Geek, 89), (arup, 22), (Pankaj, 18)]     Geek       arup     Pankaj
```

I currently have my df column as:

```
dframe1['best match'] = dframe1['matches'].str[0] #first best match (new column)
dframe1['best 2'] = dframe1['matches'].str[1] #2nd best match
dframe1['best 3'] = dframe1['matches'].str[2] #3nd best match
```

I have tried using str.extract but I am confused on how to only focus on grabbing the alphabet pattern.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with pandas, but are you sure you want that `.str` in there?  It looks a lot like you have tuples, in which case it's a lot easier to just access the first element of the tuple than to convert it to a string and then parse the result into the first element of the original tuple.

Comment: Hi @atom, inside your Pandas Data Frame, are this plain Python touples `("aparn", 91)`?

Comment: @Samwise I thought I would have to convert it into a string bc I have to merge another dataframe that contains a list of strings that I would like to match with other columns in relation to the strings. I am new to pandas as well but I will definitely try your approach.

Comment: @KonstantinA.Magg I believe they are, it is coming from a line used to find the closes match between two strings. The line of code: for i in list1:
    mat1.append(process.extract(i, list2, limit=3)) data dframe1['matches'] = mat1

Comment: @atom, does the suggested answer work for you (see below)?

Answer (score 0):

my first guess is, your problem is not about string handling but about accessing the items inside the array and the tuple. Does this work for you?

```
dframe1['best match'] = dframe1['matches'][0][0] #first best match (new column)
```

A few comments as explanation:

- `dframe1['matches'][0]` addresses the first item in your array: `("aparn", 91)`. This is a Python tuple
- `dframe1['matches'][0][0]` addresses the first item in this tuple: `"aparn"`

More details about handling tuples in Python: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_tuples.asp

Comment: This is my mistake- I realize it is not a tuple; instead, this is a list because of the brackets. The solution did not work, there was a valueError: Length of values (3) does not match length of index (4).

Comment: Hi @atom, thanks for your response. Can you provide a bit more details, please? What is _this_ (that is a list) and what code did produce the `ValueError`? - Feel free to update the question above to add more clarity

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is to use the function `.apply`.

I added `.apply(lambda x: x[0])` to the end of `dframe1['best match'] = dframe1['matches'].str[0]` and the wanted output was successfully created.

`dframe1['best match'] = dframe1['matches'].str[0].apply(lambda x: x[0])`

also ty @KonstantinA.Magg and @Samwise for the help. It is a tuple, that def help with searching for the right function to use.